# Can I use CSound in lua without knowing C?

Tags: c++, lua, csound

I'm trying to learn my first computer language, lua, which will be interpreted by a musical synthesizer module running C++ code at a lower level. I'm wondering if I can use CSound without coding C++ at all, only lua.

I want to use CSound code because I believe that lots of useful code is open source. I am yet to do any programming of the synthesizer, just learning my my first language right now.

Comment: the question may be awful, in which case i'm sorry. it would take many hours work just to find out it is

Comment: if someone has written a wrapper for Lua then you should be able to.

Comment: @macroland thanks! i'll google 'wrapper'

Comment: https://github.com/csound/csoundAPI_examples/tree/master/lua

Comment: @macroland so that is a yes then? i won't be able to read the lua code there yet...

Comment: i don't suppose i can have an upvote, else i won't be able to ask another question and so, at this rate, be unable to learn lua